# How to find the previous URL in admin-on-rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

In my`<Edit>` component I want to know what url I came from.
I need it to choose the redirect way after submit form with `<SaveButton>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it just to go back to where you came from or something else? If it's just to go back to where they came, then you can just use the `history` API and `history.goBack(-1)`. That's how the 'Go Back' button works in the default `catchAll` page.